# Most efficient way to search a nested list for a tuple in Scala

Tags: scala, search

I want to search a nested list for a tuple but I want to know the most efficient way to do so in Scala. For example, `List[(String, Int)] = List((b,1), (c,1), (d,1))` say I want to search whether `(c,1)` exists in it. I could use contains, or find but in terms of efficiency what is the fastest way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List#contains` *is* the fastest way to do it. It will make at most one pass of the `List`, and stops as soon as it finds a match. Unless you know the list is sorted, you can't make it any faster. The Scala collections library is written in such a way that all (if not, most) of the elementary functions are optimized for performance.

See the [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/092690e7bf71bb22e6e57afb7ea7f67fdfe31a0a/src/library/scala/collection/LinearSeqOptimized.scala#L100-L107).

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to search in `hash` based map, where "your tuple" is key. It will give you search complexity `O(c)`